# Can't get Allow Sorting to work on a gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview that doesn't sort when I set AllowSorting = true, the headers don't turn into hyperlinks. I have the columns SortExpression set so I'm not sure whats going wrong. I have tried to implement a onSorting function but that doesn't work either. The data is bound in a different library with a functino call. If someone could point me in the right direction any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663532/How-to-Perform-Sorting-in-Gridview-in-ASP-NET

Comment: can u update your answer with the way you are doing

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
   <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" ShowFooter="false" 
    AllowSorting="true">
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#85C1E9" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#85C1E9" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="14px" Font- 
 Names="Time New Roman" />
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" 
  />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#85C1E9" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="Black" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F5F5F5" />
```

> Set **EnableEventValidation="false"** at the top of the page
>
> Set header style and item style width and height for correct
>   alignments
>
> Same as you done but little modifications i did